# How to find all the tags inside a specific tag in XML

Tags: java, xml

I want to extract all the Nodes inside `<Page>` Node.
I am using below method to find all the nodes in a XML document by using below two methods

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("*");  //getting all the nodes
doc.getElementsByTagName("name"); //getting nodes <name>
```

but I want to find all the nodes inside a specific node. As for example I want all the nodes inside `<page>`. Please suggest me a way to do it...

```
<Pages>
      <Page>
            <Diagram>
                <Widgets>
                    <Image>
                        <Name>YmcLogo</Name>
                        <Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle X="0" Y="4" Width="130" Height="28" />
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Bold>False</Bold>
                        <BorderColor>Color(argb) = (255, 0, 0, 0)</BorderColor>
                        <BorderWidth>-1</BorderWidth>
                        <FillColor>Color(argb) = (255, 255, 255, 255)</FillColor>
                        <FontName>Arial</FontName>
                        <FontSize>9.75</FontSize>
                        <ForeColor>Color(argb) = (255, 0, 0, 0)</ForeColor>
                        <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>
                        <Italic>False</Italic>
                        <Underline>False</Underline>
                        <VerticalAlignment>Center</VerticalAlignment>
                        <Widgets>
                            <TextPanel>
                                <Html>&lt;p style="font-size:13px;text-align:center;line-height:normal;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:'Arial Regular', 'Arial';font-weight:400;font-style:normal;font-size:13px;color:#000000;text-align:center;line-height:normal;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</Html>
                                <Name />
                                <Rectangle>
                                    <Rectangle X="2" Y="6" Width="126" Height="16" />
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Bold>False</Bold>
                                <BorderColor>Color(argb) = (255, 0, 0, 0)</BorderColor>
                                <BorderWidth>-1</BorderWidth>
                                <FillColor>Color(argb) = (255, 255, 255, 255)</FillColor>
                                <FontName>Arial</FontName>
                                <FontSize>9.75</FontSize>
                                <ForeColor>Color(argb) = (255, 0, 0, 0)</ForeColor>
                                <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>
                                <Italic>False</Italic>
                                <Underline>False</Underline>
                                <VerticalAlignment>Center</VerticalAlignment>
                            </TextPanel>
                        </Widgets>
                    </Image>
                        <ShapeType>H2</ShapeType>
                        <Annotation>
                            <Properties>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="ContainerType">conditionContainer</PropertyValue>
                            </Properties>
                        </Annotation>
                        <FootnoteNumber>1</FootnoteNumber>
                        <Name>SCMProductGroup</Name>
                        <Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle X="72" Y="110" Width="127" Height="15" />
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Underline>False</Underline>
                        <VerticalAlignment>Near</VerticalAlignment>
                    </Shape>
                    <Textbox>
                        <Text />
                        <Annotation>
                            <Properties>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="ContainerType">conditionContainer</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="field_label[多言語対応用キー][多语言对应Key]">label.scmProductGroup</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="type">text</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="cvcodeobjary ">scmProductGrp</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="cvcontainerobjary ">scmProductGrpNm</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="cvfieldstrary ">scmProductGrpName</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="cvopenmethod ">scmProductGrp_ajax_codeValue</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="maxlength[桁数-最大][最大位数]">3</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="size">3</PropertyValue>
                            </Properties>
                        </Annotation>
                    </Textbox>
                    <Textbox>
                        <Text />
                        <Annotation>
                            <Properties>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="ContainerType">conditionContainer</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="type">text</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="datatype">String</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="styleClass">display</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="full-width">False</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="half-width-al">True</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="half-width-num">False</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="half-width-other">False</PropertyValue>
                            </Properties>
                        </Annotation>
                    </Textbox>
                    <Table>
                        <Annotation>
                            <Properties>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="ContainerType">DhtmlX Grid Container</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="maxlength[桁数-最大][最大位数]">3</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="size">3</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="group-name">1</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="group-type">list</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="collection">result</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="edit[入出力区分][输入区分]">true</PropertyValue>
                                <PropertyValue PropertyName="sort">True</PropertyValue>
                            </Properties>
                        </Annotation>
                        <FootnoteNumber>5</FootnoteNumber>
                        <Name>DHTMLXgrid</Name>
                        <Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle X="20" Y="180" Width="812" Height="140" />
                        </Rectangle>
                        </Table>
                </Widgets>
            </Diagram>
            <PackageInfo>
                <Name>01::inquiry::list</Name>
            </PackageInfo>
      </Page>
</Pages>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all nodes with name `<page>`

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("page");
```

If there are many, iterate over them and for each get children

```
for (Node node : list)
{
   //Get all nodes inside the this <page> element
   NodeList childList = node.getChildNodes();
}
```

If you truly want all the nodes contained inside each `<page>`, you will need a recursive funtion. This one will fill a list that it gets as a parameter:

```
public void getAllChildren(ArrayList<Node> list, Node parentNode)
{
    NodeList childList = parentNode.getChildNodes()
    for(Node node : childList)
    {
       list.add(node);
       getAllChildren(list, node);
    }
}
```

To use this function

```
ArrayList<Node> allNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

//Get the first node of all elements of <page>
Node pageNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("page").item(0);

getAllChildren(allNodes, pageNode);

//Now every child and child of child etc is on allNodes
```

Comment: This is fine milez I am able to extract all the page nodes but I want all the nodes inside a page node.

Comment: This is what the childList does? each `node` is a page and you call getChildNodes on it to get another level of nodes

Comment: childNode returns just one level below Nodes .It never returns all the nodes Inside any node.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan then you need a recursive funtion, such as one that i edited to my answer

Comment: Is there any function which can be called on any node to bring all the nodes inside it? As this method getElementsByTagName("*") returns

Comment: I wrote one for you, give it a list that you want to contain nodes and a parent node where searching begins

Comment: Node pageNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("page").get(0); this line is throwung error as get(0) is not allowed here

Comment: YES  item(0) is working but it is returning all the text values instead of nodes only..                                                                                                                         [[#text: 
   ], [Diagram: null], [#text: 
    ], [Widgets: null], [#text: 
     ], [Image: null], [#text: 
      ], [Name: null], [#text: YmcLogo], [#text: 
      ], [Rectangle: null], [#text: 
       ], [Rectangle: null], [#text:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84452/discussion-between-milez-and-shashi-ranjan).

Answer (score 1):

Get the page element, then use [`Element.getElementsByTagName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) (not `Document.getElementsByTagName`). For example:

```
Element pageElement = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("Page").item(0);
NodeList result = pageElement.getElementsByTagName("Name");
```

Comment: result will contain list of <name> node only... but I want all the nodes inside a particular node.as for example document.getElementsByTagName("*")=> this will bring all the nodes inside a document in similar way I want a list of all the nodes inside any specific node

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.Element

Comment: @ShashiRanjan, you've imported the wrong class. Use `org.w3c.dom.Element` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Learn a bit of [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). XPath is a small language specifically designed for getting specific part of an XML document.

For example, to get all *child* elements of `<Page>` you can simply write `//Page/*`. Or if you rather want *descendant* elements of the same, use `//Page//*` :

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Page//*");
NodeList result = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

For reference :

- [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java) : I don't actually code in Java, sample codes above adapted from this link
- [w3school XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) : gentle introduction to basic XPath syntax, cross-check with [the official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) of XPath 1.0 if you have doubt